# Add Properties to KinectTileButton

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, kinect

(vs express2012, WPF, .net4.5)
I am new to C# development.
I am currently developing a windows app using the kinect SDK 1.7

I want to style a KinectTileButton at runtime but not sure how, I have tried various solutions found on Stack but none have worked, I am assuming this is probably due to my lack of C# knowledge, so please provide answers for dummies.

The xaml markup is:

```
<k:KinectTileButton Background="{x:Null}" 
    BorderThickness="3" Height="Auto" Margin="50,0" 
    BorderBrush="#FF181919" Width="Auto" />
```

the problem is the KTB's are created dynamically at runtime.
In code behind:

```
for (var index = 0; index < 300; ++index)
{

    var button = new KinectTileButton ();
    this.Width = Double.NaN;

    Image img = new Image();
    if (files[fileindex].FullName.EndsWith(".jpg"))
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(files[fileindex].FullName));

    button.Content = img;
    this.wrapPanel.Children.Add(button);
    fileindex++;

    if (fileindex >= files.Length) 
        fileindex = 0;
}
```

I amended the code, maybe it might help those developing with MS kinect who arent that great at C#.

After a little tinkering and some help from this is how I styled the KTB

```
var button = new KinectTileButton ();
button.Background = null; 
button.Margin = new Thickness(40); 
button.Height = Double.NaN; 
button.Width = Double.NaN;
button.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
```

Comment: How do you want to style the KTB?

Comment: Like the styling displayed in the xaml markup.

Comment: `button.Background = null; button.BorderThickness = 3; button.Height=Double.NaN;` a.s.o...

Comment: Thanks @Florian GI I get the following Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Windows.Thickness' Pls advise

Comment: Sry, I forgot that BorderThickness has to be of type Thickness: button.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3); should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure WHERE you're creating your `KinectTileButtons` but I'll work under the assumption that you're doing it in the codebehind of one of your outer controls(`Window`). You can create the style in `XAML` and then use [`FindResource(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) to assign it in codebehind. If you do it this way, you'll be able to reuse the style for multiple buttons.

**XAML**:

```
<Window>
    ...
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="KinectButtonStyle" TargetType=k:KinectTileButton>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="40">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            ...
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

**Codebehind:**

```
var button = new KinectTileButton
{
    Style = FindResource("KinectButtonStyle") as Style
}
```

In fact, if you were to remove the `Key` from the `Style`, it would get applied implicitly and you wouldn't need to do the `FindResource(...)` lookup. I don't know whether that's desirable or not for you.